# byobu: change background or marking for zoomed splits?

Tags: byobu

I usually work with several splits in a window and zoom in one of the splits to make use of the screen. And I also work with serveral windows at a time. So when I jump back and forth for a while, it is hard to find out which window that has a zoomed split. Is there a way to make the zoomed split easily recognizable, i.e. change its background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the bottom of [Byobu](http://byobu.org), in the window naming, there's a "Z" that indicates that your window is zoomed.

It is not possible to change the background color in tmux.  That's a tty limitation.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org).*